# multiple names for one host in ssh_config

Tags: ssh

I have a hosting account which allows ssh login.  There are several web sites on my hosting and each has its own ssh login, so I login as:-

```
ssh websitename@myhost.co.uk
ssh anothersite@myhost.co.uk
ssh yetanothersite@myhost.co.uk
```

What I hoped to do in ssh_config was something like:-

```
Host websitename anothersite yetanothersite
    Hostname myhost.co.uk
    User %h
```

But this doesn't work because the %h doesn't substitute in the User line.

Does anyone have any idea how I can achieve what I want, enter just the site name (well, it's actually just the first 8 letters of the site name) after ssh and get the result 'ssh sitename@myhost.co.uk'?

Comment: Might be simpler to alias the hosting server name (`Host h` `Hostname myhost.co.uk` and then do `ssh websitename@h`). Or write a shell function `sshh() {ssh "$1"@myhost.co.uk;}`

Answer (score 7):

You can use multiple `Host` directives, like that:

```
Host websitename anothersite yetanothersite
    Hostname myhost.co.uk

Host websitename
    User websitename 

Host anothersite
    User anothersite 

Host yetanothersite
    User yetanothersite
```

to achieve what you want.

That is not perfect, as you will have to duplicate the hostname/username several times, but AFAIK the best you can do with `ssh_config`.

Alternatively consider using a shell-level aliases, like that:

```bash
>alias websitename="ssh websitename@myhost.co.uk"
>websitename
```

or even a function:

```bash
>wssh() { ssh $1@myhost.co.uk }
>wssh anothersite
```